# При отправке формы нет введенного текста

Tags: php

Не получается самое простое в php. Вот код страницы

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Форма с запросом имени</title>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Ну и как тебя зовут?</h1>
<!--Форма-->
<hr />
 <form method = "post"
       action = "hiUser.php">
 Введи свое имя:
 <input type = "text"
        name = "userName"
        value = "">
<br />      
 <input type = "submit">
<!--Форма-->
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Это простая форма с запросом имени, если ввести что-нибудь в форму и нажать кнопку, нас отправят на `hiUser.php`, но введенного имени нет. Что делать - все перепробовал. Вот код страницы `hiUser.php`:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Хай чувак</title>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Хай чувак</h1>
<h3>Эта прога на PHP знает твое имя!</h3>
 <!--PHP код проги-->
<?php
  print "твое имя:$userName";
?>
<!--PHP код проги-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'Твое имя: '.$_POST['userName'];
```

Ваши ошибки:
[echo](http://www.php.su/functions/?echo) а не print
[$_POST](http://www.php.su/learnphp/vars/?reserved) что это?

Comment: Спасибо большое!
А почему не работает мой вариант я ведь взял его с учебника по php?

Comment: @phpcross, обновил

Answer (score 0):

если таккое написано в учебнике  - то учебник плохой. 
К данным пришедшим от юзера лучше всегда обращатся через массив $_POST[] или $_GET[].
То что написано в учебнике будет работать на сервере с настройкой register_global=on, что по моему мнению является дополнитльным инструментом для взлома